# System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions - CreateEntryFromFile giving "because it is being used by another process" on zip

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-3.0

I am trying to compress 1 file into a new archive.  The below code works.... most of the time.  However, once in a while (network issues?) I changed the code (see below) to create a unique name, but I still occasionally get this error.

Is there any way to work around this problem?  I'm on powershell 3 so compress-archive isn't an option, though I can probably get pscx installed.

```
Exception calling "Open" with "2" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file '\\path\share$\folder\filename_20200221_14__20200224_102143.zip' because it is being used by another process."
At line:3 char:5
+     [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]$ZipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile] ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

Here's the code I'm using.

I'm doing a "foreach ($file in $files_to_process)", but was able to duplicate the error by using a foreach {} to set variables, then run the below code.  Subsequent runs are working, naturally.

```
$timestamp = (get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")

# Now create the zip file and remove the old one 
[string]$zipFN = "$OnPremDirectoryDone$($file.basename)__$($timestamp).zip"
[string]$fileToZip = "$OnPremDirectory$($file.name)"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]$ZipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($zipFN, ([System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update))
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($ZipFile, $fileToZip, (Split-Path $fileToZip -Leaf))
$ZipFile.Dispose()
remove-item "$fileToZip"
```

Comment: I'm going to guess the file is perhaps on a shared file server or system multiple users can access? It doesn't appear to be a PowerShell issue and more that the file is already in use? Go to compmgmt - shares, look for open sessions which may be using the file itself.

Comment: @matthew I wish you were right.  Yes, it is, but the folder itself is located in a specialized enough subsubsubfolder, and I'd be the only one looking there.  And the time between creating the file (the Open $zipFN) and adding the file (CreateEntryFromFile) is short enough I can't imagine anything hitting it.  When it works it's about a second to get to the Dispose, which seems to be what actually writes it to disk.  Thanks, though!

Comment: Your .Open() method is what's throwing the exception.  If this code is used in a loop then your have a race condition where the file is not finished adding to the zip before you access it again.  If this is NOT in a loop then some other process has your file open.  You need to look at the handles accessing that file to determine what process has it open (e.g. AV, backup software, powershell.exe, etc.)